# Laptop screen full of snow when waking up, temporally fixed by restarting

Tags: display, suspend, hardware, monitor, hibernate

I have a TUXEDO Pulse 14 Gen1 running 20.04.1-Ubuntu. Since yesterday, every time I wake up my laptop from sleep or hibernation, the laptop screen is full of snow. I have not installed any new drivers or anything, although I cannot rule out if the system has done so in the background.

Even if the laptop screen is full of snow, I can connect an external monitor and work on that just fine. I can also switch between extending and only using one monitor. If I choose to only use the external monitor, the laptop screen goes black. As soon as I attempt to use the laptop screen, it is again full of snow. Once I restart the laptop, everything is fine again until it goes to sleep, after which there's the snow again!

At first, I thought it might be a loose connection, however, since it consistently and only happens when the computer wakes up, it might also be a software issue. Does anyone have an idea (besides reinstalling Ubuntu) how I could figure out if it is software or a hardware issue? And if it is a software issue, how to fix it?

This is what it looks like:
[laptop screen with snow and okay external monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaAX4.jpg)

Some info on my system:

```
USER@USER-TUXEDO-Pulse-14-Gen1:~$ uname -a
Linux USER-TUXEDO-Pulse-14-Gen1 5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 14 00:32:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
USER@USER-TUXEDO-Pulse-14-Gen1:~$ ps -e | grep tty
   1139 tty7     00:00:26 Xorg
   1142 tty1     00:00:00 agetty
USER@USER-TUXEDO-Pulse-14-Gen1:~$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path              Device     Class          Description
===========================================================
                                 system         TUXEDO Pulse 14 Gen1 (PULSE1401)
/0                               bus            PULSE1401
/0/0                             memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/a                             memory         32GiB System Memory
/0/a/0                           memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Un
/0/a/1                           memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Un
/0/c                             memory         512KiB L1 cache
/0/d                             memory         4MiB L2 cache
/0/e                             memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/f                             processor      AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Gr
/0/100                           bridge         Renoir Root Complex
/0/100/0.2                       generic        Renoir IOMMU
/0/100/1.2                       bridge         Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0          wlp1s0     network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/1.3                       bridge         Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.3/0          eno1       network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gi
/0/100/8.1                       bridge         Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 
/0/100/8.1/0                     display        Renoir
/0/100/8.1/0.1                   multimedia     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AM
/0/100/8.1/0.2                   generic        Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Plat
/0/100/8.1/0.3                   bus            Renoir USB 3.1
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0      usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/3               multimedia     HD Webcam
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/4               bus            USB2.0 Hub
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/4/4             communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1      usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.4                   bus            Renoir USB 3.1
/0/100/8.1/0.4/0      usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.4/1      usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.5                   multimedia     Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir A
/0/100/8.1/0.6                   multimedia     Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD A
/0/100/8.2                       bridge         Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 
/0/100/8.2/0                     storage        FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/8.2/0.1                   storage        FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/14                        bus            FCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.3                      bridge         FCH LPC Bridge
/0/101                           bridge         Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/102                           bridge         Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/103                           bridge         Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/104                           bridge         Renoir Device 24: Function 0
/0/105                           bridge         Renoir Device 24: Function 1
/0/106                           bridge         Renoir Device 24: Function 2
/0/107                           bridge         Renoir Device 24: Function 3
/0/108                           bridge         Renoir Device 24: Function 4
/0/109                           bridge         Renoir Device 24: Function 5
/0/10a                           bridge         Renoir Device 24: Function 6
/0/10b                           bridge         Renoir Device 24: Function 7
/0/1                             system         PnP device PNP0c01
/0/2                             system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/3                             input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/4                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/5                  scsi1      storage        
/0/5/0.0.0            /dev/sda   disk           1TB Samsung SSD 860
/0/5/0.0.0/1          /dev/sda1  volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/5/0.0.0/2          /dev/sda2  volume         923GiB EXT4 volume
/0/5/0.0.0/3          /dev/sda3  volume         8191MiB Linux swap volume
```

Comment: Maybe update for kernel comes in? `tail -n 20 /var/log/apt/history.log` Have you tried to boot an older kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug introduced in kernel version 5.13

In this thread they recommend going back to kernel 5.11

"Looks like the 5.13 kernel has a bug regarding amdgpu"

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/flickering-snow-on-laptop-screen-in-ubuntu-20-04-with-470-drivers/201275/2

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thank you for contributing.  Please take the [tour].